# I need to set a notification on a specific day every week.. but I don`t care the day of the month

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, ios9, xcode7

My question is the same question that I linked below but I want to do that in swift 2, not in objective-c

[Fire a notification at a specific day and time every week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110805/fire-a-notification-at-a-specific-day-and-time-every-)

The problem is that the date that I'm using is by default 1st January, because I haven't specified the month, the day of the month and the year, But if I specified them it would be useless because my app wouldn't work next year, or next month

Is very simple what I want.. Set a notification weekly on Sunday (For example)

but is not practical to specify the year or the month, because it should work any Sunday or any Saturday

please help me :( I've already tried a lot

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = NSDateComponents()


components.hour = 2
components.minute = 54
components.weekday = 6

var newDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = newDate
notification.alertBody = "Swipe to unlock"
notification.alertAction = "You've got a class soon!"
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear


UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

UPDATE:

I know it will only work on Mondays but I can fix later.
The problem here is that I set the hour and minute in 0 and then it returns the current time and I do not know how to set up the hour that I want.

```
var pickerDate = NSDate()
print(pickerDate)

var dateComponents: NSDateComponents? = nil
var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()


dateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.NSWeekdayCalendarUnit, fromDate: pickerDate)
var firstMondayOrdinal = 9 - dateComponents!.weekday
dateComponents =  NSDateComponents()
dateComponents!.day = firstMondayOrdinal
dateComponents?.hour = 0
dateComponents?.minute = 0
var firstMondayDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents!, toDate: pickerDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
dateComponents?.weekdayOrdinal = 1



let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = firstMondayDate
notification.alertBody = "Swipe to unlock"
notification.alertAction = "You've got a class soon!"
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear


UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: Your question is how to get the next Sunday at a specific time to set the firedate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32518640/2303865

Comment: mmm I want to fire a notification at a specific day of the week every week, for example: I want to fire a notification every Monday at 8 AM. I could do that with the components of the date but it will only work today, if someone open my app next year, te fire date will be in the past

Comment: You didn't understand. Get the next Sunday or Monday date, use calendar method dateBySettingHour to set the desired time to that date and use it as the firedate using the weekofyear repeat interval

Comment: My app is a schedule for my courses at university, so I have to attend every week, and the courses are not entered manually, They are selected from a json database, in that database I can obtain the day of the week and the hour

Comment: aaah I got it, I'll try it, thank you :D

Comment: woow it is a big step, I can now obtain the nearest day that I want, but I can´t set the hour and the minute that I want, it use the same hour and minute of the moment that the code runs, so the hour is variable, if I write dateComponents.hour = 10 it is not 10 :S  there is a difference. I'll try to figure it out, thank you Leo :)

Comment: You probably forgot to cancel previously scheduled notifications

Comment: I am not sure if it makes a difference but try setting the time zone before setting the firedate

Comment: mmm the date that returns comes with the day that I want, but with the current hour and minute, and if I set dateComponents.hour = 1, the hour will be increase in 1, if the hour was 9 now it's 10

Comment: the problem is that the hour and the minute that comes with the date will vary according to the time you run the code

Comment: Please update your question with your actual code. I am sure it is probably a small mistake

Comment: I did it , thank you :)

Comment: If you would like me to post my comments as an answer so it can help future visitors with similar issue, please let me know otherwise just delete your question.

Comment: Yes I'd like you to :D

Comment: Done. You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the next Sunday or Monday date ([SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32518640/2303865)), use calendar method dateBySettingHour to set the desired time to that date and use it as the firedate using the weekofyear repeat interval.